# How to check to see if something has a value in it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make a tic tac toe game and I getting stumped. Basically the Tic Tac Toe board works and I am able to place X's and O's respectively per player, but when I click the cell again, it will replace it with an X or an O. For example if a cell had an X in it and you click it again an O appears. My question here is, how can I check to see if the said cell has an X in it, and then save it there and make it so it cannot be changed. From there I want to try to do win conditions which is probably just if cell1 && cell2 && cell3 === "X" then just say you win or something. Anyway any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/78pu4y7t/11/

```js
var nextTurn = "X";


function clickButton()
{
if(this.id === "t1")
{
 if(document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
  
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t2")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t2").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
  
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t3")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
  
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t4")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t4").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t4").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t5")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t5").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t5").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t6")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t6").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t6").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t7")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t7").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t7").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t8")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t8").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t8").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

else if(this.id === "t9")
{
 if (document.getElementById("t9").innerHTML = "");
 {
  document.getElementById("t9").innerHTML = nextTurn;
  turnSwitch();
 }
}

}

document.getElementById("t1").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t2").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t3").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t4").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t5").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t6").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t7").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t8").onclick = clickButton;
document.getElementById("t9").onclick = clickButton;


function turnSwitch()
{

if(nextTurn === "X")
{
 nextTurn = "O";
}
else
{
 nextTurn = "X";
}
 
}
```

```css
td{
border: 2px solid green;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="t1"></td>
  <td id="t2"></td>
  <td id="t3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="t4"></td>
  <td id="t5"></td>
  <td id="t6"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="t7"></td>
  <td id="t8"></td>
  <td id="t9"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a rather simplified approach:

```js
var nextTurn = "X";

// eventObj is the automagically passed Event object:
function clickButton(eventObj) {
  // the target of that event object is the one on which the event originated:
  var clicked = eventObj.target;

  // if the trimmed length of the innerHTML of the clicked element is falsey
  // (so zero), then we go inside the 'if':
  if (!clicked.innerHTML.trim().length) {
    // set the innerHTML of the clicked element:
    clicked.innerHTML = nextTurn;
    // invoke the turnSwitch function:
    turnSwitch();
  }
}

// document.querySelector returns the first and only match to the given
// CSS selector; addEventListener assigns the click event-handling function:
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', clickButton);

function turnSwitch() {
  // if nextTurn is currently 'X', we change it to 'O'; if it's anything other than 'X',
  // we update it to 'X':
  return nextTurn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="t1"></td>
    <td id="t2"></td>
    <td id="t3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="t4"></td>
    <td id="t5"></td>
    <td id="t6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="t7"></td>
    <td id="t8"></td>
    <td id="t9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it's worth noting, of course, that your original assessment (`if (document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML = "")`) was *assigning the value* (and therefore evaluating to a truthy value), instead of *assessing* it and evaluating 'accurately'; you need to use: `if (document.getElementById("t3").innerHTML === "")` instead.

Comment: I am replying to every comment like this but I just want to say thank you very much. I really appreciate it @David Thomas

Comment: @Glorpy but it is really important that you learned about the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself). If many lines of code look the same, chances are you can restructure them.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to unregister the event handler once a user has selected it.
e.g.

`document.getElementById("t9").innerHTML = nextTurn;
document.getElementById("t9").onclick = null;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator to compare the values. You should use a comparison operator; `==` or `===` instead of the assignment operator `=`:

```
if(document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "");
```

should be:

```
if(document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML === "");
```

---

Side note: Instead of getting the id of the element to use it to find out what element to work on, and then getting a reference to the element using an id, you can just use the reference to the element directly. This vastly simplifies the event handler code:

```
function clickButton()
{

    if (this.innerHTML === "");
    {
        this.innerHTML = nextTurn;
        turnSwitch();

    }

}
```

Comment: I am replying to every comment like this but I just want to say thank you very much. I really appreciate it @Guffa

Answer (score 0):

In your conditions (`if` clauses) you are using an assignment (`=`) instead of comparator (`===`). That means each time that `if` is evaluated, the `innerHTML` of the element in question is reset to empty string.

```
if (document.getElementById('...').innerHTML === '') {
    // ...
}
```

will work just fine.

Comment: I am replying to every comment like this but I just want to say thank you very much. I really appreciate it @hon2a

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

```
if(document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "");
{
```

A single `=` is assignment, so you're setting innerHTML to empty string every time. You want `===` (strict equality test)

Secondly, you can't have a semicolon at the end of this line, I'm not even sure what this statement is evaluating to but it's not correct syntax `if(document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = "");`

Thirdly, Javscript has a concept of "truthiness," meaning anything evaluated in a boolean context (like an `if` statement where it will check true / false) will be cast to `true` or `false`.

So you can short circuit what you're doing using truthiness:

```
if( !document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML ) {
```

which will work if there is **not** ( the `!` operator) any innerHTML. You could also explicitly look for empty string by fixing your `=` operator:

```
if( document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML === '' ) {
```

It's best practice to use `===` if you know the types are going to be the same. It's also best practice to put curly brackets on the same line as the statements.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate it. All these comments really helped out! It is nice to finally understand something and get it so I wont have to ask next time. Thanks again!